# Why doesn't exist birthday claim on Google provider authentication?

Tags: asp.net-core, google-oauth, google-authentication

App: .Net Core 3 with Identity.

When app authenticates with Google it gets photo, locale, usersurname, username...
But I can't get birthdays. I have searched in internet for two days but didn't get a solution.

Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddGoogle(options =>
                {                    
                    IConfigurationSection googleAuthNSection =
                        Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Google");
                    options.ClientId = googleAuthNSection["ClientId"];
                    options.ClientSecret = googleAuthNSection["ClientSecret"]; 
                     // scope for birthday
                    options.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read");                   
                    options.AuthorizationEndpoint += "?prompt=consent";                   
                    options.AccessType = "offline";
                    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("avatar", "picture", "url");
                     options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("locale", "locale", "string");

                    // all they don't work:
                    //options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("birthday", "birthday", ClaimValueTypes.String);
                    //options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.DateOfBirth, "birthdays");
                    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.DateOfBirth, "birthdays", ClaimValueTypes.String);                   
                    options.SaveTokens = true;

                    options.Events.OnCreatingTicket = ctx =>
                    {
                        List<AuthenticationToken> tokens = ctx.Properties.GetTokens().ToList();

                        tokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken()
                        {
                            Name = "TicketCreated",
                            Value = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()
                        });


                        ctx.Properties.StoreTokens(tokens);

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    };
                });
```

Account/ExternalLoginModel.cs

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetCallbackAsync(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
{
//....
 var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
// Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login.
 var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor: true);

foreach (var i in info.Principal.Claims)
{
   // get all claims from Google, except birthday.
   Console.WriteLine(i.Type + " " + i.Value);
}

}
```

Google OAuth consent screen
[image: In Google Console is birthday scope]

On https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get I get birthday:

```
"birthdays": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "primary": true,
        "source": {
          "type": "PROFILE",
          "id": "11"
        }
      },
      "date": {
        "year": 1930,
        "month": 12,
        "day": 26
      }...
```

How I can get in .Net Core birthday claim?

Comment: Have you tried makeing a request to the google people api and getting it back that way?

Comment: @DaImTo I worked by this  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/additional-claims?view=aspnetcore-3.0. And I don't know how I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue. also I tried to use Google OpenId Connect REST APIs and data required not returned even if I add "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read" scope to auth request.

As per my search, fields like "Gender" and "birthdays" is not part of the standard and you need to access the provider APIs to get such information.

For me I'm using IdentityServer4 so I added blow code in ProfileService to get the required claims and add them to user claims:

```cs
// Create Credentials required from access token
// PeopleServiceService nuget:Google.Apis.PeopleService.v1

var cred = GoogleCredential.FromAccessToken("ACCESS_TOKEN");
var peopleServiceService = new PeopleServiceService(
    new BaseClientService.Initializer() { HttpClientInitializer = cred });

// use people/me to access data for the current authenticated user 
var personRequest = peopleServiceService.People.Get("people/me");
personRequest.PersonFields = "birthdays,genders";

Person person = peopleRequest.Execute();

// you can access now 
// person.Genders, person.Birthdays
```

In your case you may add the claims when 'OnCreatingTicket' executed:

```cs
// options.Events.OnCreatingTicket = ctx => { --> 

Person person = peopleRequest.Execute();
var genderValue = person.Genders?.FirstOrDefault()?.FormattedValue;

var claimsIdentity = ctx.Principal.Identities.First();
claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("Gender", genderValue));


tokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken()
           {
               Name = "TicketCreated",
               Value = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()
           });
```

People API documentation:
https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get